# How to change the retention period for Firefox Sync data?

Tags: firefox, sync

I'm running an own Firefox Sync server based on the following instructions: http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync.html

I know that clients only appear in the client list (e.g. at about:sync-tabs) if they have updated their status in the last X days.

How can I get how many days the retention period is and where can I adjust it?